# How to enable highlighting for initial value in quarter datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Regarding the quarterPicker for the Bootstrap datePicker ([SO: how-to-change-bootstrap-datepicker-month-view-to-display-quarters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383750/how-to-change-bootstrap-datepicker-month-view-to-display-quarters), jsfiddle: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mwk0d5L/1/)):

How can an initial value be highlighted on startup?

I supplied a value in

```
window.onload
```

but it is not displayed when starting up the webpage. But if I change the quarter and re-open the dialogue, the quarter is highlighted correctly.

Comment: Can you show the code where you supplied the value in `window.load` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#example1').datepicker('setDate', 'Q1 2018');
$('#example1').datepicker('update');
```