# How to select quarter date from the date popup not the actual date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I want exactly the same thing like in the following image.

[image]

Is it possible? any jquery library or some custom thing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383750/how-to-change-bootstrap-datepicker-month-view-to-display-quarters